# How do I merge one SQL 2005 Table with another Table?

Tags: sql, merge, insert

I have two tables both with one column each. I want to copy/merge the data from those two tables into another table with both columns. So in the example below I want the data from **Table1** and **Table2** to go into **Table3**.

I used this query:

```
INSERT **TABLE3** (BIGNUMBER)
SELECT BIGNUMBER
FROM **TABLE1**;
INSERT **TABLE3** (SMALLNUMBER)
SELECT SMALLNUMBER
FROM **TABLE2**;
```

When I did this it copied the data from Table1 and Table2 but didn't put the data on the same lines. So it ended up like this:
[image: Simple SQL Merge Wrong]

I am trying to get the data to line up... match. So BIGNUMBER 1234567812345678 should have SMALLNUMBER 123456 next to it. If I am querying I could do this with a JOIN and a LIKE 'SMALLNUMBER%' but I am not sure how to do that here to make the data end up like this:
[image: Simple SQL Merge Correct]

It doesn't have to be fancy comparing the smallnumber to the bignumber. When I BULK insert data into TABLE1 and TABLE2 they are in the same order so simply copying the data into TABLE3 without caring if SMALL is the start of BIG is fine with me.

There is no relationship at all in these tables. This is the simplest form I can think of. Basically two flat tables that need to be merged side by side. There is no logic to implement... start at row 1 and go to the end on BIGNUMBER. Start at row 1 again and go to the end on SMALLNUMBER. All that matters is if BIGBUMBER has 50 rows and SMALLNUMBER has 50 rows, in the end, there is still only 50 rows.

When I was using the query above I was going off of a page I was reading on MERGE. Now that I look over this I don't see MERGE anywhere... so maybe I just need to understand how to use MERGE.

Comment: Is there any relationship between bignumber and smallnumber? If so, what is it? If not, please tell us and edit you question to remove all similarity so the sample data doesn't suggest a relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the order of numbers is not important and you don't want to add another field to your source tables as jcropp suggested, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` function within a `CTE` to align a number to each row and then make a join based on them

```
WITH C1 AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TABLE1.BIGNUMBER) AS Rn1
           ,BIGNUMBER
    FROM TABLE1
)
,C2 AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TABLE2.SMALLNUMBER) AS Rn2
           ,SMALLNUMBER
    FROM TABLE2
)
INSERT INTO TABLE3
SELECT C1.BIGNUMBER
       ,C2.SMALLNUMBER
FROM C1
INNER JOIN C2 ON C1.Rn1 = C2.Rn2
```

More information about [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), [`CTE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.90).aspx) and [`INSERT INTO SELECT`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

Comment: This might work as well... I have never heard of a CTE before. The actual names of the tables are all TEMPXX because I am working with temporary data. I will play with this too and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: **Update** your exact code worked perfectly. I thought it was going to go into its own temporary table in memory but it stuck it into TABLE3 where it remains. Thanks SQLUser!

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a JOIN statement to merge the two tables they each have to have a column that has common data.  You don’t have that, but you may be able to introduce it:

1. Edit the structure of the first table. Add a column named something
   like `id` and set the attributes of the `id` column to `autonumber`. 
   Browse the table to make sure that the`id` column has been assigned
   numbers in the correct order.
2. Do the same for the second table.
3. After you’ve done a thorough check to ensure that the rows are
   numbered correctly, run a query to merge the tables:

   `SELECT TABLE1.id, TABLE1.BIGNUMBER, TABLE2.SMALLNUMBER INTO TABLE3
   FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.id = TABLE2.id`

Comment: Thanks jcropp. I may be able to do this. Can you give an example of how when I do a BULK insert where I make the ID column autopopulate? I can do a new question if that is more appropriate. I have a feeling that if I try to do the bulk insert the data will try and go into the first column (ID) or error out because I didn't indicate anything going into that column.